# Embedded SQL step understanding question, I want a concrete example

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The lecture slide

[image]

Can you please provide a concrete example for the two steps involved in converting Host Language + Embedded SQL to Host Language Object code, which come after the preprocessor step? As a final year statistics student enrolled in a database system class, I feeling a bit confused about the process outlined in the attached lecture slide, and would appreciate some clarification. The class needed more computational background than I think.

I understand the host language is the language we are using, for example, it could be Python, C, Java, C++. I read the slides and textbook and searched online for the youtube video. However, without professional background, it was a bit hard for me to connect all the dots together.

Comment: Once again, thank you to anyone who helps! I really want to gain more understanding here.

Comment: For a small app this is useful. However, direclty embedding SQL in a host language doesn't scale up well for mid-size apps. You can take a look at [Pro*C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C); there are plenty of example on how a C program can make embedded SQL calls to Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I hardly ever see software developers use embedded SQL anymore in new applications. You will probably never encounter embedded SQL. It's kind of an artifact from the 1980's and 1990's. Technically it's still part of the ANSI SQL standard, but I'm surprised any lecture covers it at all.

Virtually all use of SQL these days is dynamic SQL, putting SQL inside a string variable and using an API to send that to an RDBMS server as a string. It is parsed by the RDBMS server at runtime. This is the way most SQL API's work, such as JDBC, ODBC, or the various database extensions in PHP. Even when you use an ORM library, the ORM code forms SQL in strings, and sends those strings to the RDBMS to be parsed before the query is executed.

Embedded SQL makes the SQL look like it's part of your programming language, not a string variable. You effectively get new syntax to query and fetch results, and your code is therefore written in a sort of enhanced programming language.

Here's an Embedded SQL Example from the online book [SQL-99 Complete, Really](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL8128443M/SQL-99_Complete_Really) (excerpted according to the Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0 license):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
 
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION; 
  int x; 
  int x_indicator; 
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION; 
int i; 
 
void main () { 
    EXEC SQL CONNECT TO database_or_server USER Josephine; 
    EXEC SQL DECLARE example_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT col_1 FROM T; 
    EXEC SQL OPEN example_cursor; 
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i) { 
      EXEC SQL FETCH example_cursor INTO :x INDICATOR :x_indicator; 
      if (x_indicator < 0) printf("?\n"); 
      else printf("%d\n",x); 
    } 
    EXEC SQL CLOSE example_cursor; 
    EXEC SQL DISCONNECT database_or_server;  
}
```

You can see that this basically looks like C code, but there are a number of lines, prefixed with EXEC SQL, which are part of the code. They aren't strings like most use of SQL today.

You have to run some kind of preprocessor tool during development, just before you compile your code. The preprocessor outputs code in the host language (C in the example above), ready to compile. The `EXEC SQL` statements will have been parsed and replaced by a series of low-level API calls that submit queries and fetch results.

One advantage of embedded SQL is that all your SQL is parsed before compile-time, not at runtime. So there's no way it can be vulnerable to SQL injection.

A disadvantage of embedded SQL is that because the queries are fixed at compile-time, you can't change them without recompiling the application. For example, if you have a variable number of terms in a WHERE clause, or if you are trying to do a pivot-table query, you can't do it with embedded SQL. You have to do it  by preparing a query with dynamic SQL.

There are a couple of open-source RDBMS products that support embedded SQL:

- PostgreSQL supports embedded SQL in C code. See [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.5: ECPG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg.html) for some information on how to use embedded SQL with PostgreSQL.
- Firebird supports embedded SQL in C, C++, Ada, Fortran, Cobol, and Pascal. See [Firebird Application Development](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/ufb/using-firebird.html#ufb-cs-appdev-embed) and links to its PDF documentation for embedded SQL for more information.
- MySQL does not currently support an Embedded SQL precompiler. I thought I remembered it did at some point in the past, but I can't find a reference to it.
  I did find an article about an embedded SQL precompiler for MySQL implemented in `awk`: http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/precompiler-for-embedded-sql.html But I have no idea how current that is, or if it is abandonware. It isn't part of the official MySQL product.

Comment: Bill, thank you so much for the detailed interpretation! I do appreciate your answer. If you do not mind, may I ask about the difference between interactive SQL interfaces and pure SQL programs? Where I thought that their difference is if the SQL command interacted with the user or not. then I found it is not true, because for the Embedded SQL, I could also interacted with the user

Comment: There's no difference. SQL does not interact with users any more than `fopen()` interacts with users. Maybe I don't understand what you're asking.